# How to get total time between two dates based on condition in SQL Server 2008 while data inserting continuously by service?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want `outtime` column data like below:

```
vehicle Condition       Synctime                  outtime(hours)
----------------------------------------------------------------
1              1        2017-09-20 8:30:10         null
1              0        2017-09-20 10:30:10        2
2              1        2017-09-19 8:30:10         null
1              1        2017-09-20 13:30:10       
1              0        2017-09-20 15:30:10        2
2              0        2017-09-19 10:30:10
1              1        2017-09-20 18:30:10
2              1        2017-09-19 12:30:10        2
```

Here I want to get total time between times based on condition(1-in 0-out) and  vehicle(when vehicle **out** and when it is **in**).data ll inserting continuously as shown above. How can I achieve? Please help me.

Comment: i want procedure for this. i ll pass vechile and dates(from date and todate) from front end to procedure.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: procedure will make it very easy. Order on Vehicle and Synctime. You will get the value from previous row.

Comment: Could you make little bit clearer the condition? For example, how do you calculate "2" for outtime column? You are filling this column with 1-0,1-0 and 2-1 (vehicle-condition) conditions, and I don't understand the condition. And if you started to write any query could you add it to your question?

Comment: @sarslan ... here "2" is total time between condtion 1 and 0 where vehicle 1. i just putted example time like "2"(i want to show vehicle outtime 2hourse based on its condition). 1-vehicle is inside 2-vehicle outside based on its coordinates. data is inserting continue .

Comment: suppose: when vehicle is inside shop then condition is "1" and its time will inserted in table. when vehicle went to outside then condition is"0" and its time inserted in table. this process ll continue every day. Here i want to show" when vehicle went to outside (out-time) and again it comes to inside(in-time)  the between time want to show TOTALOUTTIME of vehicle. again vehicle ll go for out vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 hence stored procedure could be an appropriate option.

Let me add here one SP which will accept `vehicle` as parameter and return record-sets. I have assumed name of table with data is `VehicleTracking`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalclulateVehicleDurationInShop
    @vehicleID int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Vehicle INT, @Condition bit, @Synctime Datetime, @Outtime Datetime
DECLARE @VehiclePreviousRow INT, @ConditionPreviousRow bit, @SynctimePreviousRow Datetime

--Set values for PreviousRow as NULL
SET @VehiclePreviousRow = NULL
SET @ConditionPreviousRow = NULL
SET @SynctimePreviousRow = NULL

--Temp table to store result. one can use recordset and return it.
DECLARE @TEMPvehicletracking TABLE (vehicle bigint, condition bit, synctime datetime, outtime int NULL)

DECLARE Vehicle_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT vehicle, condition, synctime 
    FROM VehicleTracking 
    WHERE vehicle = @vehicleID
    ORDER BY vehicle, synctime ASC

OPEN Vehicle_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Vehicle_Cursor INTO
    @Vehicle, @Condition, @Synctime

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF(@Condition=1) 
    BEGIN
        --Vehicle IN. Store these values in values for previous record. 
        SET @VehiclePreviousRow = @Vehicle
        SET @ConditionPreviousRow = @Condition
        SET @SynctimePreviousRow = @Synctime

        --Insert record into table for incomming vehichle
        INSERT INTO @TEMPvehicletracking VALUES(@Vehicle, @Condition, @Synctime, NULL)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Insert in temp table 
        INSERT INTO @TEMPvehicletracking VALUES(@Vehicle, @Condition, @Synctime, DATEDIFF(hh, @SynctimePreviousRow, @Synctime))
        --Set value for PreviousRow as NULL as it will be another set of in-out record. 
        SET @SynctimePreviousRow = NULL
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Vehicle_Cursor INTO
    @Vehicle, @Condition, @Synctime
END
CLOSE Vehicle_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Vehicle_Cursor

--result will be return via SP from this SQL
select * from @TEMPvehicletracking

END
```

**NOTE:** This SP doesn't accept date range for which result could be filtered before returning. Fromdate and Todate can be passed as parameter to SP to filter out result-set. The purpose of SP is to guide towards achieving a solution. Error handling, and optimizing it has not been considered.

Comment: The above logic giving only diff time between coming row and previous row based on condition. but in my case when condition=1(in-time) and condition=0(out-time). there are so many records ll insert with condition=0 after condition-1 i need to calculate total time from condition-1 to  condition-0 up to getting again condition=1

Comment: @NarasinghRao There is one assumption in above solution that is: there will be ordered IN-OUT-IN for a vehicle. That assumption is true for time management system. Now, since data has been ordered based on time hence it is expected that there will be ordered IN-OUT-IN-OUT records. But one can modify the procedure to take care of unordered/missing IN-OUT records too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
--Sample Data
DECLARE @OuttimeTable  TABLE (Vehicle INT, Condition INT, Synctime DATETIME )
INSERT INTO @OuttimeTable VALUES 
(1, 1, '2017-09-20 8:30:10')
,(1, 0, '2017-09-20 10:30:10') 
,(2, 1, '2017-09-19 08:30:10')  
,(1, 1, '2017-09-20 13:30:10')       
,(1, 0, '2017-09-20 15:30:10') 
,(2, 0, '2017-09-19 10:30:10')
,(1, 1, '2017-09-20 18:30:10')
,(2, 1, '2017-09-19 12:30:10') 

SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    CASE WHEN T1.Condition = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, T.Synctime, T1.Synctime) END Synctime
FROM @OuttimeTable T1
    OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM @OuttimeTable T2 
        WHERE T2.Condition = 1 
            AND T2.Synctime < T1.Synctime 
            AND T1.Vehicle = T2.Vehicle
        ORDER BY T2.Synctime DESC) T
```

Comment: it executing correctly. but taking too long time. in my table there 1lakh records above. and i ll pass vehiclenum and fromdate and todate from front-end to stored procedure.

Comment: Has the table index for Condition, Vehicle and Synctime?

Comment: i am sending only date( no time) and vehicleID.. i want to show all records between two dates.

Comment: Could you share your query?

Comment: thank you for your patience. i couldnt past my query. i am using  your query. i am passing vehiclenum,fromdate and todate to it. it taking too long time for execution

Comment: [--your qeury-- where T.DeviceID=@deviceid       
     and T.Synctime between @fromdate and @todate]

Comment: Your addition seems correct. Could you check your indexes?

Comment: while executing with select *from tbl1 where Deviceid=111., result getting fast.(within 5 sec) but in above query its taking 1min above. and what is indexes here?

Comment: After change table and column names according to your table, could you create this index: CREATE INDEX IX_tbl1_Deviceid_Condition_Synctime ON tbl1(Deviceid, Condition, Synctime)

Comment: How is the result now?

Comment: same sir. taking too long time. my fields(Sid,deviceid,contion,Synctime) and here SID is sequence number for deviceid and when i execute " select SID from tbl1 where Deviceid=1" it showing sequence number(1,2,3,4...).

Comment: Could you send me Execution Plan?

Comment: here i couldnt give indexes. becausei have no permission to add indexes to tbl. i created procedure with your logic. it giving correct results. but executing too slow. can you make it to execute fast.please

Comment: There is no way to make this query faster without creating necessary indexes.

Comment: Thank You. i achieved this by only inserting  intime record and last outtime record. now getting between time of these two records. thank your query helped me lot.